# How to store unlimited data to a particular column in mysql

Tags: php, mysql

One of my php project using mysql as the database.In at this projects PHP front end will alow user to modify the database. And it is having a column stores the data that user enters.

Earlier I was using datatype as sallint(255). when the database starts to grow requirement automatically demanded more storage for the  data which user enters, so that i changed the datatype to TEXT now there is a particular point raised which demands more data storage than that of TEXT can offer. Is there any way a particular column can offer unlimited data storage?.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are two more types you can see:

1. **`LONGTEXT`**: A TEXT column with a maximum length of 4,294,967,295 or 4GB (2^32 – 1) characters. The effective maximum length is less if the value contains multi-byte characters. The effective maximum length of LONGTEXT columns also depends on the configured maximum packet size in the client/server protocol and available memory. Each LONGTEXT value is stored using a four-byte length prefix that indicates the number of bytes in the value.
2. **`LONGBLOB`**

Answer (score 0):

BLOB and TEXT values can be extremely long, you might encounter some constraints in using them:

Only the first max_sort_length bytes of the column are used when sorting. The default value of max_sort_length is 1024. You can make more bytes significant in sorting or grouping by increasing the value of max_sort_length at server startup or runtime. Any client can change the value of its session max_sort_length variable:

```
mysql> SET max_sort_length = 2000;
mysql> SELECT id, comment FROM t
    -> ORDER BY comment;
```

Instances of BLOB or TEXT columns in the result of a query that is processed using a temporary table causes the server to use a table on disk rather than in memory because the MEMORY storage engine does not support those data types

Comment: I am extremely not understood what you said here but i am accepting second answer its worked well for me thank you.